# Українські відповідники до слова "реінжиніринг"?

Tags: іменники, іншомовні-слова, відповідник

Цікавить, чи є українські відповідники до слова [*реінжиніринг*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) у значенні процесів, які покращують рейтинг і успішність якоїсь певної компанії. Цікавить це слово саме в контексті такому:

> **Реінжиніринг бізнес-процесів** полягає в революційному усуненні в компанії кризових явищ (точкове покращення бізнес-процесів), комплексній трансформації компанії (комплексне покращення бізнес-процесів), створенні і підтримці системи безупинних покращень результативності бізнесу.

В словнику синонімів відповіді не знайшла. Є  лише іншомовні [відповідники](https://pidruchniki.com/71696/logistika/kontseptsiya_reinzhiniringu_logistichnih_protsesiv):

> Як синоніми реінжинірингу бізнес-процесів у фаховій літературі можна зустріти такі терміни, як **Business Reengineering (BR), Business Process Redesign (BPR), Business Process Improvement (BRI).**

Comment: Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання про переклад містило: (1) пояснення **своїми словами** іншомовного слова; (2) **контекст**, в якому автор збирається використовувати перекладене слово; (3) продемонструвати власну спробу знайти відповідь і (4) пояснити, чим са́ме знайдені варіанти не підходять. Запитання, які не відповідають цим умовам, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді.

Comment: Дякую за зауваги. При редагуванні цього запитання намагалася врахувати всі критерії

Comment: @bytebuster, по-моєму, недоліки було усунуто — як вважаєте?

Comment: @Sasha, дякую за нагадування. Я свій мінус зняв ще коли improved someone else's edit.

Comment: Engineering - розробка чогось, Reengineering - переробка чогось, т.т. повторно розробити. Design - конструювання чогось,  Redesign - реконструкція чогось. Але тут є нотки значення "відновлення після поломки", тому я б лишив дизайн та ре-дизайн. Їх значення - концептуальна розробка/переробка системи.   Improvement  - покращення. Зазвичай це щось на порядок простіше за переробку чогось.